# how to consume wcf service in portable class library and want to add the reference in shared project (I am using Xamarin.Forms Portable) in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, wcf, xamarin

**how to consume wcf service in portable class library and share UI code in Android, iOS, and Window Phone platform in Xamarin ?**

I want to make common object of WCF for all project(Android, Windows and iOS).

I want to add the reference in shared project (I am using Xamarin.Forms Portable).

How to develop xamarin.forms hello world Demo apps using WCF Services?

Already read all tutorials and show the all examples. But in my case..
I am created a Xamarin Native Apps using Portable Class Library.
I have a four Project in single solution.

1. NativeAppsWithWCF(Portable)
2. NativeAppsWithWCF.Droid
3. NativeAppsWithWCF.iOS
4. NativeAppsWithWCF.WinPhone

I want to add web reference in NativeAppsWithWCF(Portable) project. and do all operation of Android, iOS and WinPhone using Portable Class Library Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Please can you clarify who "Jason Already" is? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Sorry for that... by mistake i typed "Jason" word.

Answer (score 1):

Parts of System.Web.Http are not available in a PCL.  If you're consuming a asmx or other heavy proxy webservice, you're basically not going to be able to do that in the PCL.

However you can quite easily wrap that in an interface, then just make a version per platform, and inject it into your PCL code to keep as much of the logic as possible there.

Also when you do web calls with Xamarin, I strongly recommend using ModernHttpClient - you'll see a big performance difference there!

Comment: I have already created proxy of wcf webservices using Silverlight 5.0. But how can i access webservices Method response in App() class in Portable Class Libarary ?

Comment: You need to define an interface in the PCL, and implement it in the platform code.  

So if you're calling the asmx service to get a return type of string, for example
```
public interface ICallMyService{
   string DoTheThing();
}
```

You then implement this interface in the iOS or Android project to actually call the asmx service.

Also, don't do any processing in the App class!  That breaks every rule of single responsibility, and will leave your code a pile of spaghetti very soon.